# strategy pattern no access to getters

Tags: java, getter-setter, strategy-pattern

### Structure

```
-ClassA
|---|
|---ClassAImplA
|---ClassAImplB
-Main
```

### Class A:

```
public interface ClassA {

    public void execute();

}
```

### Implementaion A:

```
public class ClassAImplA implements ClassA 
{
    private int a = 5;

    public ClassAImplA (int a){setA(a);}
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println(a);

    }
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
```

### Implementaion B:

```
public class ClassAImplB implements ClassA 
{
    private boolean b = false;

     public ClassAImplB (int a){setB(b);}
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println(b);

    }
    public booelan getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setA(boolean b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
```

### main:

```
public class main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        ClassAImplA param1 = new ClassAImplA(10);
        ClassA = param1;
    }


}
```

By doing this I make `ClassA` interchangeable, 
but `I` lose the capability to access the parameter `int a`.
Is there a way to still make it interchangeable, and still have access to `int a`, 
or in case of `ClassAImplB`, the field `boolean b` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, but it's not a good idea to do, as it defeats the purpose:

```
ClassAImplA param1 = new ClassAImplA(10);
ClassA = param1;
if (param1 instanceof ClassAImplA) {
    param1x = (ClassAImplA) param1;
    System.out.println(param1x.getA());
}
```

But don't do this. It defeats the purpose of the pattern.
The purpose of the pattern is to use objects of type `ClassA`,
without having to know how they work.
The `getA` method is only defined in `ClassAImplA`,
it's an implementation detail that should not be relevant to users of the `ClassA` type.
They shouldn't have to know. It's hidden.
This is called good encapsulation and information hiding.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought too but how do you then save a instance of such an implementation like ClassAImplA?

Comment: What do you mean by save? Perhaps this is what you're looking for: `ClassA param1 = new ClassAImplA(10);` (yes this works)

Comment: Well yes that is what I am doing in my main function. But now I need to save that instance, so I need to be able to access its parameters.(int a)

Comment: If you need to access its parameters, then you need to save it as a `ClassAImplA`. For example you could have a `Collection<ClassA>` of all the objects, and have another `Collection<ClassAImplA>` with an extra copy of strictly the `ClassAImplA` objects.

Comment: But that defeats the whole purpose, I don't know what type ClassA implementation I'll have.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of the Strategy pattern. The whole purpose of that pattern is that you can have multiple implementations and you don't have to know what they are. If you want to know what they are, then the Strategy pattern is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you need one more class using composition to decide which implementation is needed.

```
 public ClassHelper{
     private A a;

     public ClassHelper(A a){
      this.a = a;
     }

     public void execute() {
      this.a.execute();
}


 }  


  public class main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static  void main(String[] args) {
    ClassHelper param1 = new ClassHelper(new ClassAImplA(10));
    param1.execute();

   //or when you need classBIMpl

   param1 = new ClassHelper(new ClassAImplB(true));
    param1.execute();


}
```

}

And about the ability to access member of implA or implB , no you cannot have that flexibilty with this patter, whole point of this pattern is that caller need not be aware of implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface for the strategy and a Factory with different overloaded methods to create the concrete instances of the classes. Of course the methods are typed to the interface instead of the concrete classes.

The interface.

```
public interface Strategy {
  void execute();
}
```

The first implementation.

```
public class ConcreteStrategy implements Strategy {

  private boolean a;

  public ConcreteStrategy(final boolean a) { this.a = a; }

  public void execute() {}
}
```

The second implementation.

```
public class AnotherConcreteStrategy implements Strategy {

  private int a;

  public AnotherConcreteStrategy(final int a) { this.a = a; }

  public void execute() {}
}
```

The factory.

```
public class Factory {

  public static Strategy create(final boolean a) {
    return new ConcreteStrategy(a);
  }

  public static Strategy create(final int a) {
    return new AnotherConcreteStrategy(a);
  }
}
```